# Image-menu with hover-effect with one image only?

Tags: html, css, menu, typo3

I've built a site with TYPO3 (4.7.2) which has a nice graphical menu on the right hand side (see [here](http://podologen-symposium.de)). But this is not so user-friendly nor is it easy to maintain, as it is a bit of a hack and doesn't use "Typo3-Standards", but just some general HTML/CSS-hacking:

the menu's html is:

```
<p id="kat">
 <a target="_blank" href="http://www.fusspflege.com/elkat/op/">
  <img src="/fileadmin/images/baehr_katalog2.png" />
 </a>
</p>
```

and the corresponding CSS:

```
  #kat a {
    background: url("/fileadmin/images/baehr_katalog2_hover.png") no-repeat;
    display:block; height:120px; width:220px; /* Linkbereich begrenzen */
  }

  #kat img {
    display:block; width:220px; height:120px; border:0;
  }

  #kat a:hover img {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
```

So basically I show the image with white font in "standard mode" and when the mouse hovers, that image is hidden and the same image (with black font) in the background becomes visible. I thought this was quite nice, and it did not need any JS :-)

But I'm wondering if there is a way to do this more elegant, robust and user-friendly (*perhaps with TYPO's tools?*), so that the user could change images if needed without having to worry about CSS...

**edit:** I found a solution requiring one image! (Text is in transparent colour and the CSS has this:

```
  #kat a:hover img {
    background-color: black;
  }
```

But still I wonder if there's not a more TYPO-esque solution around?  ;-)

Comment: I can't for the life of me figure out why you're messing around with images over something so painfully simple in CSS.

Comment: You refer to my initial approach? Simple reason: that transparency-idea did not occur to me before today! :((

Comment: I refer to any approach that puts text in images without cause. It makes maintenance, adjustment, and updates a real pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As edited in the q, I found a solution:

Text is in transparent colour and the CSS has this:

#kat a:hover img {
    background-color: black;
  }

(In order to avoid issues created by non-CI fonts and to maintain good looks etc., I prefer captions as part of img vs. CSS-styled text.)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use text links (only image) you are able to switch properties like this:

```css
#kat a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    width: 220px;
}
#kat a img {
    border: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    opacity: .5;
}

#kat a:hover img {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 1s ease 0s;
}
```

```html
<p id="kat">
    <a target="_blank" href="http://www.fusspflege.com/elkat/op/">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/440/220"/>
    </a>
</p>
```